# PBW basis and canonical basis

Tags: lie-algebras, quantum-groups, canonical-bases

Consider the example of $\mathfrak{g} = sl_3$. Then 
$$
\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{n} \oplus \mathfrak{h} \oplus \mathfrak{n}^{-},
$$
where $\mathfrak{n}$ is generated by $E_{12}, E_{13}, E_{23}$, $\mathfrak{h}$ is generated by $E_{11}-E_{22}, E_{22}-E_{33}$, $\mathfrak{n}^{-}$ is generated by $E_{21}, E_{32}, E_{31}$, $E_{ij}$ is a matrix with $1$ at $(i,j)$ and $0$ elsewhere.

A PBW basis of $U(\mathfrak{n})$ is 
$$
B_1 = \{ E_1^a (E_1 E_2 - E_2 E_1)^b E_2^c \mid a, b, c \in \mathbb{N} \}.
$$

There is another basis of $U(\mathfrak{n})$ called canonical basis which is given by
$$
B_2 = \{ E_1^aE_2^bE_1^c \mid a+c \geq b \} \cup \{ E_2^aE_1^bE_2^c \mid a+c \geq b \}.
$$

The basis $B_2$ has a property: given a lowest weight vector $v_0$ of a representation $V$ of $U(\mathfrak{n})$, the set
$$
\{ b v_0 \mid b v_0 \ne 0 \}
$$
is a basis of $V$.

My question is: in general, how to compute canonical basis for $U(\mathfrak{n})$ explicitly like the above example. Can we derive a canonical basis from a PBW basis? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please say what is $E_1$ and $E_2$ in the given bases? The original bases for the Lie algebra is in terms of $E_{i,j}$, so these bases also should be in terms of  $E_{i,j}$ no? why in terms of $E_1$ and $E_2$ ?

Comment: @GA316, sorry, I used different notations. Here $E_1=E_{12}$, $E_{2}=E_{23}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to obtain the canonical basis from the PBW basis, as long as you are working in the quantum group U<sub>q</sub>(n). The canonical basis seems to be inherently a quantum phenomenon, so it shouldn't be surprising that we want to compute in the quantum group.

If E<sub>π</sub> is an indexing of the quantum PBW basis, then what one first proves is that applying the bar involution is unitriangular with respect to this basis. There is even a mathoverflow question about this: [Convex PBW bases](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110108/).

Now it is a matter of linear algebra to prove that there exists a unique bar invariant basis b<sub>π</sub> such that
$$b_\pi=\sum_\sigma c_{\pi\sigma} E_\sigma$$
with c<sub>σσ</sub>=1, c<sub>σπ</sub>∈qℤ[q] if σ≠π and c<sub>σπ</sub>=0 unless σ≤π. This basis b<sub>π</sub> is the canonical basis.

Comment: This is illustrated in Lusztig's original J.A.M.S. (1990) paper in low rank examples.   Also, some computational methods are given in papers by W.A. deGraaf: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1959260, http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1987542